# Python and Selenium bindings Error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser, python-3.4

I am facing Errors while running this code to do the binding of python and selenium. whether it's working correct or not.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

But i am facing lot errors.Please help me where i am doing wrong.

Here i am attaching the screenshot for your reference.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `geckodriver` to use Firefox.
Download and install it from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Comment: Hi alex, I have installed geckodriver but the problem is i don't have permission to set environment variables.may be that's why i am facing issue

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to set variables in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed geckodriver at right location.

Open terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

Now open this directory and command ls to see if geckodriver is in this path.